# Insert PDF file into word document using python

Tags: python

I need to insert PDF file into the word document using python. I have created the table in word document and trying to insert the PDF file into the word document but i can't able to insert it. Anyone please suggest me the way tp insert the PDF file into word document. Expected output would be like this.[[image: Inserting the PDF file into word document1]

Comment: @Rahul Agarwal
Could you please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
import win32com.client as win32

## This block of code is to embed the pdf files into the word document

```
    try:
        word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
    except AttributeError:
        # Corner case dependencies.
        import os
        import re
        import sys
        import shutil
        # Remove cache and try again.
        MODULE_LIST = [m.__name__ for m in sys.modules.values()]
        for module in MODULE_LIST:
            if re.match(r'win32com\.gen_py\..+', module):
                del sys.modules[module]
        # shutil.rmtree(os.path.abspath(win32com.__gen_path__+'/..'))
        shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(os.environ.get('LOCALAPPDATA'), 'Temp', 'gen_py'))
        word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')

    # word.Application.Visible = False
    doc1 = word.Documents.Open(file_path)

    pdf_icon = str((base_path/"pdf.ico").resolve())
    # netlist_icon = str((base_path/"list.ico").resolve())

    doc1.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(FileName = 'File Name',  DisplayAsIcon = True,  IconFileName = pdf_icon,
            IconLabel = Path('path_to_pdf_file', Range = doc1.Tables(1).Cell(2, 1).Range)
    print('PDF file embedded.')

    doc1.Close()
    word.Application.Quit()
```